# Override visual swatches

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to override visual swatches rendering in a custom module so that I can tweak some of the default behavior.

I believe two of the important files for this are:

- module-swatches/view/frontend/templates/product/layered/renderer.phtml **(file 1)**
- module-swatches/Block/LayeredNavigation/RenderLayered.php **(file 2)**

I also have noticed that **file 2** has a variable $_template referring **file 1**.

Also, **file 2** is referred in variable $block of another file:

- module-swatches/Model/Plugin/FilterRenderer.php

So, my approach is using preference in di.xml to override these classes and variables $_template and $block. But nothing works!

I would really appreciate some help! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was on the right track, but a bin/magento setup:di:compile was necessary...